# Laravel how to trail POST request

Tags: laravel

How can i see which classes are being used when i send an POST request to my api? I have a Laravel API which has been build by someone else and the code is not acting like it should. I want to see how the request is being handled.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is any middleware that could be intercepting the request?

Comment: @Rwd the api is very complicated. I couldn't find a middleware which causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you need is a profiler. Laravel has its own profiler called [Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope). It is going to give you much more information about your request lifecycle.

P.S. I assumed that you ask about tools for a local environment. You haven't specified it. As for remote/production profilers, it's a different topic.

Comment: Thanks i will try this.

Answer (score 1):

This artisan command may get you started:

```
php artisan route:list --path=your-path --method=POST
```

(Replace 'your-path' with the actual path)

It lists the controller action and middleware for this route as registered by the framework.

Comment: I needed more detail about the routing process. Thank you for answering but the Telescope answer is what fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the routes in either `routes\web.php` or `routes\api.php`, in your case your api route will most likely be in `routes\api.php`. There, you can find the corresponding controller and method name that handle your request.

Comment: This isn't a routing problem. I've used `dd()` in the controller where it should go and it only triggers in `__construct()`. I've checked the routes with `php artisan route:list` and it says that it should go to the function `store()` which he doesn't. Also checked the middleware and didnt find anything.